# MSBuild Copy Output Assembly to Additional Dir

Tags: .net, msbuild, .net-reflector

### Problem

Visual Studio's Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Host.exe holds a read lock on `%DEVPATH%\*.dll` during build.

### Background

I'm running a website on my development box with Redgate .NET Reflector.  .NET Reflector requires that the environment variable `DEVPATH` be set to `%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Red Gate\.NET Reflector\DevPath\` so that it can create PDBs of referenced assemblies without putting them in your bin directory.  When it does create PDBs, it copies the disassembled .dlls to `DEVPATH` and whatever program you're running references these copies rather than the files in your bin dir.

That's fine except that, in my case, these disassembled dlls use reflection and look in the same directory they are in, assuming it to be the original bin dir, for other assemblies--the ones I've written.

Here's my directory structure:

```
/inetpub/wwwroot/bin/Arena.Framework.dll          <-- dll to be decompiled
/inetpub/wwwroot/bin/Arena.Custom.Common.dll      <-- my custom dll

/ProgramData/Red Gate/.NET Reflector/DevPath/Arena.Framework.dll    <-- copied by .NET Reflector in order to be decompiled; uses reflection to find types in ./Arena.Custom.*.dll
```

### Things that didn't work

#### Symbolic link

First I tried using a symbolic link from `.../bin/Arena.Custom.Common.dll` to `%DEVPATH%/Arena.Custom.Common.dll`, but that prevented building at all.

#### Have .NET Reflector copy dlls for me

Next I tried making .NET Reflector generate PDBs for my custom dll rather than having MSBuild do it so that it would automatically copy my dll into the directory.  Unfortunately, .NET Reflector is too smart for its own good, recognizing that it's a project dll, and won't do it.

#### Copy dlls after build in csproj

My next solution was to add a few lines in my `Arena.Custom.Common.csproj` file:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
  <Copy SourceFiles="@(MainAssembly)" DestinationFolder="$(DEVPATH)" SkipUnchangedFiles="true" Retries="0" />
  <Message Text="Copied @(MainAssembly) to $(DEVPATH)" />
</Target>
```

This will copy the output dll to `DevPath`.  This worked the first time I built, and I thought I was done.  The next time I built, however, it failed because **Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Host.exe** (hereafter referred to as Host.exe) has it loaded.  I assume the reason it can overwrite files in the `bin` directory is that it doesn't actually load them, but copies them to a temp directory and loads those each time you build.  However files in `DEVPATH` are always loaded by by VS's Host.exe.  As .NET Reflector only decompiles dlls that you aren't building yourself, it never needs to copy over those, and thus never runs into the issue I'm having.

### Possibly useful info..?

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185330.aspx) says you can disable the hosting process in the csproj properties window, and I did so, but it's still running.  I'm not certain, but I'm guessing the website project is causing it to run, and a Website's properties window doesn't have a "Debug" tab.

### Question

Is there a better work-around than merely copying them to `DEVPATH` after build?

Maybe I should change the output directory from `.../bin` to `DEVPATH` directly?  That would copy all the dependency dlls to `DEVPATH` as well, which isn't ideal.

Perhaps there's a way to either tell Host.exe to unload the files during build, or to kill the process until the build is finished?  I tried do this manually and MSBuild.exe started crashing.

I've considered saving a temp copy of `%DEVPATH%`, clearing the value, somehow retarting Host.exe, building, copying, setting `%DEVPATH%` back to the original value, and restarting Host.exe again, but I get the feeling that, if Host.exe is enabled, VS relies on it to be running continuously during build.

Another work-around is to close VS, delete the files in `DEVPATH`, reopen VS, and rebuild every time I need to make changes to my DLLs.  This is an awful option, but it works.

Hopefully there are some better solutions out there...

### Edit

Per comment, my question is:
How can I copy the new version of my compiled DLLs to `DEVPATH` on/after build?

Comment: I read your post twice and maybe it's me but still haven't figured out what your question is, what you want to achieve? Can you add that to the post in preferrably a single sentence..

Comment: I'm with @stijn. I read your post yesterday and couldn't figure out what you're doing or trying to do. "When it does create PDBs, it copies the disassembled .dlls to DEVPATH and whatever program you're running references these copies rather than the files in your bin dir." What does that mean? A dll which has been disassembled (to IL?) is not executable as such.

Comment: @stijn Added a single sentence question

Comment: @RenniePet I'm not sure what exactly .NET Reflecroe does with the dlls in order to generate PDB files for them aside from making copies into %DEVPATH%.  IIS seems to prefer dlls in %DEVPATH% to those in bin if they have the same name.  The framework I'm using (with no say in the matter) uses reflection to detect the path of the assembly (now in DEVPATH rather than bin) and then look for custom dlls in the same path.  Since mine aren't being copied by .NET Reflector, the framework doesn't see my dlls.  The solution, then, is to copy my dlls to DEVPATH when they're compiled.

Comment: Beginning to get an idea of what you're saying, I think, maybe. But what exactly is your current problem? Something about files being locked? Why is that a problem, what are the symptoms?

Comment: @RenniePet Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Host.exe apparently opens all DLLs in %DEVPATH%.  It doesn't close them on build, so attempting to copy the newly compiled dlls over the old versions in %DEVPATH% causes an access denied error.  I need to make ...Host.exe never run, close Host.exe during build and reopen it after, make Host.exe close the old versions of the DLLs so they can be overwritten and reopen them, or magically make my framework DLL find DLLs in bin while it's being run from %DEVPATH%.